# I want to create a charity coin

Tags: solidity

I was wondering if there were any coders or anyone that could help me with the code where there would be a fee on transfer, let's say 9% for example, and 4.5% goes to a charity wallet and the other 4.5% to a locked liquidity pool wallet, possibly even 3% charity wallet, 3% static reward for dev wallet (if I burn my tokens at beginning ensuring safety), and the last 3% back into that liquidity pool wallet.

Further questions:
-How would I even implement it into a code?
-Is there a website where I could have the coin generated then just add the fee on transfer code?
-I see other tokens using this model, is there way I could just use their code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need either to learn how to code or hire someone.

To start I suggest looking youtube for "how to code an Ethereum token with Solidity".

As for your specific tokenomics you can  look at any of the existing charity token contracts and build from there.

I'm not sure you can use this website to request volunteers in personal projects such as this.

As for website to use to generate tokens, the most used is https://remix.ethereum.org that doesn't require installation of any software to deploy a Solidity smart contract (the token or other).